# In C++, how can I use wstringstream to combine/concat wstring + NULL + DWORD

Tags: c++, null, stringstream, wstring, dword

I want to create a wstring which will have a  wstring + NULL + DWORD 
e.g. L"Text" + NULL + 0x001A. Can I use wstringstream to create such string which has a string ending char "\0" in between ?

```
hex:54,00,65,00,78,00,74,00,00,00,00,00,1a,00
     T     e     x     t    \0    00    1A
```

Comment: Did you try `my_wstringstream << my_wstring << L'\0' << my_dword;`?

Comment: Yes! It will ignore the L'\0'

Comment: @Alex no, `<< L'\0'` will not ignore a null character.  `<< L"\0"` would, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a null character using the stream's `put()` method:

```
my_wstringstream.put(0);
```

Adding a `DWORD` (what you showed is actually a `WORD`) is trickier. You can't use the `<<` operator, that will format the numeric value into a text representation, which is not what you are asking for.  You would have to instead break up the value into its individual bytes, and then `put()` each byte as if it were a character:

```
my_wstringstream.put(0).put(0x00).put(0x1A);
```

However, note that `wchar_t` is *not* 2 bytes on every platform, it *may* be 4 bytes instead.  So, using `std::wstringstream` and `std::wstring`, you are not *guaranteed* to get the *exact* output you are looking for on all platforms.  you might end up with this instead:

```
hex:54,00,00,00,65,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,74,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,1a,00,00,00
     T           e           x           t          \0          00          1A
```

If you need consistency across multiple platforms, you can use `std::basic_stringstream<char16_t>` and `std::u16string` instead.  Or, use `std::stringstream` and `std::string` (which are based on 1-byte `char`) and just write out all of the individual bytes manually.

Comment: I think that this question is liked to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53074177/3868464).

Answer (score 0):

If your question is continuing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53078619/3868464), this is copy-paste parts from my code (with removal of comments and surroundings):

```
DWORD dwReaderState, dwSessionID;
CStringW wszReaderName;
CString strTemp;
BYTE pReaderBuff[64];
DWORD cbReaderBuff;
CRegKey regKey;
// ... Data Parsing and values joining...
cbReaderBuff = (wszReaderName.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
memcpy(pReaderBuff, wszReaderName.GetBuffer(0), cbReaderBuff);
memcpy(pReaderBuff + cbReaderBuff, &dwReaderState, sizeof(DWORD));
cbReaderBuff += sizeof(DWORD);
// Session ID
ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &dwSessionID);
strTemp.Format(TEXT("%d"), dwSessionID);
// Writing to the registry
regKey.Create(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon"), NULL, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
regKey.SetBinaryValue(strTemp, pReaderBuff, cbReaderBuff);
```